# How can I send JSON-formatted cookie data using Python on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to encode an object in a Python script and set it as a cookie so I can read it with client-side JavaScript.

I've run into problems every way I've tried to do this. Generally, the cookie is formatted in a way that makes JSON.parse() break.

My current script:

```
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
data = {"name": "Janet", "if_nasty": "Ms. Jackson"}
cookie['test'] = json.dumps(data)
self.response.headers.add_header("Set-Cookie", cookie.output(header=''))
```

... which results in

```
test="{\"name\": \"janet\"\054 \"if_nasty\": \"Ms. Jackson\"}"
```

on the client.

I don't really want to introduce a hack-y solution to replace instances of commas when they appear. Any ideas how I can pass complex data structures (both by setting **and** reading cookies) with Python?

Comment: What do you get back when reading the cookie in a request, exactly? The cookie ought to decode the same way it was encoded; if not, there's a bug in the cookie library somewhere.

Comment: I'm getting the correct value when I read the value on the server side. But when it's stored on the client, it's escaped in a strange format.

Comment: The escaping is necessary for it to make it through HTTP headers. Why does it matter what format it's stored in on the client?

Comment: It matters because I want to decode it as a JSON object using json2.js or a native browser implementation of JSON.parse(string). For now I'm hacking around it by replacing commas with "|" characters but I'd prefer to find a more robust solution.

Comment: Wow, passing data between client and server using cookies is a little... odd. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also wanted to read a cookie (that had been set on the server) on the client. I worked around the issue by base64 encoding the JSON String, however there are a few small gotchas involved with this approach as well.

1: Base64 strings end with 0-2 equal signs, and these were being converted into the string \075. My approach is to revert those characters into equal characters on the client.

2: The base64 string is being enclosed in double quote characters in the cookie. I remove these on the client.

Server:

```
nav_json = json.dumps(nav_data)
nav_b64=base64.b64encode(nav_json)
self.response.set_cookie('nav_data', nav_b64)
```

Client:

```
var user_data_base64= $.cookie('nav_data');
// remove quotes from around the string
user_data_base64 = user_data_base64.replace(/"/g,"");
// replace \075 with =
user_data_base64 = user_data_base64.replace(/\\075/g,"=");
var user_data_encoded=$.base64.decode( user_data_base64 );
var user_data = $.parseJSON(user_data_encoded);
```

I am using 2 jquery plugins here:
https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64
 and 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Note: I consider this a hack: It would be better to re-implement the python code that encodes the cookie in javascript, however this also has the downside that you would need to notice and port and changes to that code.

I have now moved to a solution where I use a small html file to set the cookie on the client side and then redirect to the actual page requested. Here is a snippet from the JINJA2 template that I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nav_data='{% autoescape false %}{{nav_data}}{% endautoescape %}';
$.cookie('nav_data', nav_data, { path: '/' });
window.location.replace("{{next}}")
</script>
```

Note 2: Cookies are not ideal for my use case and I will probably move on to Session or Local Storage to reduce network overhead (although my nav_data is quite small - a dozen characters or so.)

Comment: Ah -- very clever (and good answer; thank you). I'm currently just replacing commas with '|' and then restoring the commas later since it seems that the commas were causing the problem. It's also hacky, but sufficient for right now. I'm thinking that your approach might be a better long-term hack, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

On the *Python* side:

1. `json.dumps` the string
2. escape spaces - just call `.replace(' ', '%20')`
3. Call `urllib.parse.quote_plus()` then write the string to the cookie

On the *JavaScript* side:

1. read the cookie
2. pass it through `decodeURIComponent()`
3. `JSON.parse` it

This seems to be the cleanest way I've found.

Comment: Removing the spaces may change the value of the cookie. e.g. {1: "Hello, world!"} -> {1: "Hello,world!"}

Comment: This is so old, but you are right, i had a small error in my answer, it's corrected now. (Escape spaces, not replace)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's simpler and has less caveats. Also if you know the json data will have no spaces in the values, you can use `json.dumps(nav_data, separators=(',', ':')` and then you don't need to escape spaces.

Answer (score 0):

not sure a cookie is the best way of doing this? see the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) for info rendering data to the client